# Out of range in Ubuntu installer

Tags: boot

It is the first time I want to install this OS. Currently, I'm using Windows 10, when the Ubuntu installer starts, the monitor goes "out of range", any ideas how can I fix this?

EDIT: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaEdl.jpg (Computer components and Ubuntu version)

Comment: give us a little more info on the system your trying to use.  What video card Etc.

Comment: What release of Ubuntu?   `sudo lshw -C video` (which is list-hardware of class=video) will provide us clues as to what video hardware you are using. Did you verify your install media (ie. verify your ISO download was perfect, and the write-to-thumb-drive was validated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Immediately after booting the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, you'll see a small icon that looks like a little man next to a keyboard, at the bottom of your screen. Touch any key on the keyboard to activate a supplementary menu. Hit the <kbd>F6</kbd> function key. Select `nomodeset`. Continue booting. Install Ubuntu.